# Test if strings are equal with Junit returns false even if its egual

Tags: java, testing, junit, integration-testing

I have a method that returns a `String` and I would like to test if it works correctly. For that I have a `test.txt`-file that I read and compare to the return value of my method. If I print both `Strings` out they are exactly the same! Somehow `assertEquals` still fails.. What am I doing wrong here?

**Method to test:**

```
public String statement() {
    String result = "Rental Record for " + getName() + "\n";

    int frequentRenterPoints = 0;
    for (Rental each : this.rentals) {
        frequentRenterPoints += each.getFrequentRenterPoints();

        // show figures for this rental
        result += "\t" + each.getMovie().getTitle() + "\t"
                + " (" + each.getMovie().getQuality() + ")"
                + ": "
                + String.valueOf(each.getCharge()) + "\n";
    }

    // add footer lines
    result += "Amount owed is " + String.valueOf(getTotalCharge()) + "\n";
    result += "You earned " + String.valueOf(frequentRenterPoints)
            + " frequent renter points";
    return result;
}
```

**Test:**

```
    @Test
public void statementReturnsCorrectlyFormattedString() throws IOException {
    // given
    customer = new Customer("ElonMusk");
    
    Movie movieOne = new Movie("IronMan1", PriceCodes.REGULAR, Quality.HD);
    Movie movieTwo = new Movie("AvengersEndGame", PriceCodes.NEW_RELEASE, Quality.FOUR_K);
    
    Rental rentalOne = new Rental();
    rentalOne.setMovie(movieOne);
    rentalOne.setDaysRented(5); 
    
    Rental rentalTwo = new Rental();
    rentalTwo.setMovie(movieTwo);   
    rentalTwo.setDaysRented(1);
    
    List<Rental> rentalList = new LinkedList<Rental>();
    rentalList.add(rentalOne);
    rentalList.add(rentalTwo);
    
    customer.setRentals(rentalList);
    String expectedString = "";
    try {
        expectedString = readFile("test.txt");
        System.out.println("expected: " + "\n" +expectedString);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("Error reading statementTestFile!", e);
    }
    
    // when
    String statement = customer.statement();
    
    // then
    System.out.println("statement: " + "\n" + statement);
    System.out.println(expectedString.equals(statement));
    assertEquals(expectedString, statement); 
}
```

**Output: expectedString**

> expected:
> Rental Record for ElonMusk
> IronMan1     (HD): 6.5
> AvengersEndGame  (FOUR_K): 5.0
> Amount owed is 11.5
> You earned 2 frequent renter points

**Output: statement**

> statement:
> Rental Record for ElonMusk
> IronMan1     (HD): 6.5
> AvengersEndGame  (FOUR_K): 5.0
> Amount owed is 11.5
> You earned 2 frequent renter points

**readFile:**

```
private String readFile(String file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (file));
    String         line = null;
    StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String         ls = "\n";

    try {
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(ls);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: did you do a trim, did you check for non-printable-characters?

Comment: not yet, ill try it now

Comment: ok so `assertEquals(expectedString.trim(), statement.trim());` is actually working. But why ?

Comment: @Stultuske In `test.txt` I typed in exactly what I would expect. Is there something wrong with my `readFile` that adds non-printable characters? I added `readFile` to the qeustion

Comment: You add it yourself. After reading each line you add `\n`, it also gets added after the last line.

Comment: @pafauk. but when I delete adding `\n` in my `readFile` it still failes

Comment: check the length of both Strings, start with that

Comment: @Stultuske if I add `\n` inside readFile like in the question, the expectedLength is 136 and statementLength is 135. Withouth the `\n` expectedLength is 131

Comment: I think the problem is that at the end I add one more `\n`. how can i fix that?

Comment: I know I could just `trim` but thats not very clean...

Comment: Posted an answer, it's getting a bit too long for comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the trailing newline you add when reading from a file. You could in  trim the string, but what if there were some empty lines at the end of file you wanted to read?

So you can either introduce a 'first line' boolean like that:

```
boolean isFirstLine = true;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!isFirstLine) {
        stringBuilder.append(ls);
    }
    stringBuilder.append(line);
    isFirstLine = false;
}
```

Or maybe leave the loop as-is and after it runs delete last character from the builder with:

```
if (stringBuilder.length() > 0) {
    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1); // or stringBuilder.lastIndexOf("\n");
}
```

Or do a substring.

Or maybe read the lines into a `List` collection like `ArrayList` and later do `String.join("\n", linesCollection);`.